# Link to static JSON file

Tags: docusaurus

In Docusaurus V2 how to link to a JSON file in the static folder?

I tried the following in a markdown file:

```
An exemple, is the following [JSON dataset](../../static/data/solar-radiation.json).
```

But Docusaurus then produce the following error:

```
./static/data/solar-radiation.json (./node_modules/file-loader/dist/cjs.js?name=assets/files/[name]-[hash].[ext]!./static/data/solar-radiation.json)
Module parse failed: Unexpected token e in JSON at position 0 while parsing near 'export default __web...'
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/file-loader/dist/cjs.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token e in JSON at position 0 while parsing near 'export default __web...'
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

My file is a valid JSON. For some reason, instead of displaying a static file Docusaurus seems to try to parse it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I saw the same problem. My temporary solution is:

- Change file name from `.md` to `.mdx`
- Add this link to your json file

```html
<a target="_blank" href="/json/file.json" download="file.json">Download</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've also had the same problem!

According to the [Issue #3561 on the Docusaurus GitHub](https://github.com/facebook/docusaurus/issues/3561), word from one of the developers is that the current best practise is to use the `pathname://` prefix in front of your URL. To use your example:

```markdown
An exemple, is the following
[JSON dataset](pathname://../../static/data/solar-radiation.json).
```

Apparently the reason why this happens is because there is a conflict between the `babel-loader` (used to load code) and the `file-loader` (used to load static assets). The `pathname://` prefix skips both of these loaders, and just creates a link instead.